# Copy data to clipboard as csv file

Tags: csv, clipboard

I am looking for a smart clipboard program that I can use it to automatically create a CSV file(in the background) using data that I copy.
The purpose is to copy data and the CSV file that is formed using this data to be attached by email. (I do not want to save the CSV to the hard-disk as a preliminary step).

Thanks,
Clint

Comment: This is not a question for StackOverflow. We are here to help on programming issues, not to recommend or find software.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is a utility that does exactly what you are asking for. The purpose is simply too narrow, too unique. However you might be able to construct something yourself:

Some clipboard applications offer to run "actions" on certain events, for example when a new entry is copied. You could define an event that copies every new entry by attaching it (along with a separation character) to an existing file. Certainly, with a few tweaks here and there, you could come to a solution that does something like what you are looking for.

However this does not do any escaping, you have no control over the format (how many columns in a row?), so it is a hack, nothing satisfying. So instead you could create something slightly more convenient by implementing a tiny daemon that accepts the entries sent by the clipboard actions (via a pipe) and takes care for escaping and formatting rules. This can all be done by a shell script. You could finalize and attach the result to an email composer process upon a certain time or when you copy a certain special text or press a key combination.

I did something similar using 'klipper' once, KDE default clipboard application, which is really a great tool. Also I implemented a kio slave based (so file based) access to the clipbard history under a KDE environment years ago which could probably be used to create a tool like you are searching for. But this will only help you if you are using a KDE environment. Which is something I definitely recommend, by the way ;-)

Sorry, nothing ready-to-use, but as said you probably won't find such thing...